# mapView:viewForAnnotation: not always called

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am just starting out wit `MKMapKit` and call outs. In particular, I have started to use `mapView: viewForAnnotation:` and a right accessory button. My problem is that the method only get called for newly added pins but not for those previously added to the map view. The call out opens but without a right accessory. Should this method be called for all pins?

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    static NSString *resuseId = @"WaypointMapViewVC";

    MKAnnotationView *view =[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:resuseId];

    if (!view){
        view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:resuseId];
        view.canShowCallout=YES;

        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView=rightButton;
    } else {
       view.annotation=annotation;
    }
    return view;
```

}

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The delegate method looks ok.  Where are the "previously added" pins added?  When they are added, is the map view's `delegate` set?

Comment: Many thanks Anna. Embarrassingly only the referencing outlets was set. With the outlet delegate set it now all works. Many thanks for your help!